# Using chartJS in Angularjs to plot IOT data

Tags: javascript, beginner, json, angular.js, data-visualization

I am a Javascript and AngularJS beginner.

Below is the code inside my *chartController*. What this does is get IOT data from a back-end call and display it in my front-end with a chart. There are two helper functions for the  chart: *addData()* and *remove()* to add and remove data. These functions make it so that the chart gets *new* data to the right of the chart and removes data on the left. This is what I have so far.
It would be appreciated if someone would give me tips on how:

- to make my controller less stacked, get data -> draw chart -> update chart.
- to make the get method more generic. The URL is now hardcoded.

```
var vm = this;
vm.content = [];
vm.dataContent = [];

$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/data/Living Room'
})
  .then(function successCallback(response) {

    JSON.stringify(response.data);

    angular.forEach($scope.content, function (value) {
      vm.dataContent.push(value.inputData);

    });

    $scope.content = response.data;

    var canvas = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var dataChart = {
      labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "Testing my Set",
        data: vm.dataContent
      }]
    };;


    var settings = {
      type: "line",
      data: dataChart
    };

    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, settings);


    function addData(chart, data, label) {
      chart.data.labels.push(label);
      chart.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
        dataset.data.push(data);
      });
      chart.update();

    }

    function remove(chart) {
      chart.data.labels.shift();
      chart.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
        dataset.data.shift();
      });
      chart.update();
    }

    setInterval( function(){

      addData(myNewChart, 16,  'working on it');

      // Remove the first point so we dont just add values forever
      remove(myNewChart);
    }, 5000);



  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    return alert(response.status)
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

### Feedback

The code appears to make good use of AngularJS and ChartJS, as well as promises.

For the function that handles the response, I had to move the line that assigns *response.data* to *$scope.content* up before the call to [angular.forEach()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach). Otherwise it seems that the data wouldn't get assigned before the iteration...

Also I don't see the point of calling [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) on the response.data object unless that gets assigned to a variable or passed to another function...

> ```
> function handleResponse(response) {
>     //what is the point of this line? the return value isn't assigned to a variable or passed to a function
>     JSON.stringify(response.data);
>     $scope.content = response.data;            
>     angular.forEach($scope.content, function (value) {
>         vm.dataContent.push(value.inputData);
>     });
> }
> ```

### Recommendations

Below are my recommendations. They are by no means a definitive list of improvements but will hopefully be useful in terms of readability, flow of the code, etc. In general, I aim to avoid lengthy functions - with ~10-20 lines or fewer. For more guidance, refer to answers on [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/27798/244085).

### Making separate functions

> - to make my controller less stacked, get data -> draw chart -> update chart.

First, I would move the implementation of the *successCallback()* and *errorCallback()* functions out to be defined later. [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) can be utilized here so the functions can be defined after being called, though one could also move the definitions up if desired. And if there was a need to call the functions multiple times, then the functions could be referenced simply by name in each instance.

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/data/Living Room'
})
    .then(successCallback, errorCallback); 

function successCallback(response) {
    JSON.stringify(response.data);
    //skipping the rest of the implementation
}
function errorCallback(response) {
    return alert(response.status);
}
```

Then I would break out the blocks within *successCallback* into separate functions. Even if they aren't called in multiple places, it can improve readability. While there are varying opinions, many people argue methods should be kept between 5-15 lines (refer to [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/133406/244085) - I know that is tagged with [java](/questions/tagged/java) and [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) but it can apply to many other languages as well).

In the example below, I made one function to handle taking the response, and a separate function to get the settings passed to the chart constructor.

```
function successCallback(response) {
    handleResponse(response);

    var canvas = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, getSettings());
    setInterval( function(){
        addData(myNewChart, 16,  'working on it');
        // Remove the first point so we dont just add values forever
        remove(myNewChart);
    }, 5000);
};
function handleResponse() { ... }
function getSettings() { ... }
```

### Making URL variable

> - to make the get method more generic. The URL is now hardcoded.

There are various ways to make the URL a variable. One approach is to have it be controlled by user interaction. For example, the UI could have inputs bound to the url via [ngBind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind). And another approach might be to have specific URLs defined in the controller and reference those URLs. So in the controller, we could define:

```
$scope.urls = {
    livingRoom: 'http://localhost:8080/data/Living Room,'
    hallway: 'http://localhost:8080/data/Hallway'
}; //add more elements as appropriate
```

Then in the UI, have buttons like:

```
<button ng-click="loadData(urls.livingRoom)">Living Room</button>
<button ng-click="loadData(urls.hallway)">Hallway</button>
```

And define that function loadData like below, moving the call to $http() into it:

```
$scope.loadData = function(url) { 
    if (interval) { //check if interval is updating data periodically
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url //use variable value based on parameter from button
    }).then(successCallback, errorCallback);  
};
```

You may notice that function begins by checking `if (interval)` and if that evaluates to `true` then it will call [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) passing that value. That will handle clearing the previous interval, as long as we assign the return value from [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to that value:

```
var interval; //set scope outside functions
function successCallback(response) {
    //...handle response
    //...create chart
    interval = setInterval(function() {...},5000);
}
```

#### Demonstration

See a demonstration here in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ei32-jmk7).

#### Conclusion

If you look at the functions in [that phpFiddle example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ei32-jmk7), then you will notice that the longest function (excluding the controller callback) is ~9 lines long. This greatly enhances readbility.

#### JS error on hover

I noticed that after loading data from one source, then reloading with another source, when hovering over the chart I would see an error in my console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'skip' of undefined

That appears to be [this reported ChartJS bug](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3753).